# Converting a BitArray in to UInt32 C#

Tags: c#, bitarray, uint32

im trying to convert a

```
BitArray {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

into this:

```
UInt32 0x0000
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried creating a single-element array and using `BitArray.CopyTo`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new BitArray(yourArray).CopyTo(intArray, 0);
```

Comment: thanks... that worked for me