# c# convert a 32bit BitArray to a UInt32

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I am trying to convert 32 bits in a BitArray to a UInt32 in a 32bit c# NET4.0 app in Win7 64bit.

I have tried two techniques but both throw an exception.

When using CopyTo, it throws this:
**System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.**

```
BitArray newBits = new BitArray(32);
// (modify bits...)

UInt32[] intArray = new UInt32[1];
newBits.CopyTo(intArray, 0); // < crash
```

When manually setting the bits, it throws this when it gets to the 32nd bit (when i = 31):
**System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**

```
BitArray newBits = new BitArray(32);
// (modify bits...) 

UInt32 res = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < newBits.Length ; i++) 
{
    //Debug("i="+i+", "+newBits.Length);
    if (newBits[i]) res |= (UInt32)(1 << i); // < crash when i reaches 31
}
```

1. Why can't BitArray copy to an unsigned int?
2. Why does '1 << i' fail when i = 31 in a 32bit variable?

(sorry for the duplicate question, I tried commenting in the other post but I need 50 reputation)
[Converting a BitArray in to UInt32 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157550/converting-a-bitarray-in-to-uint32-c-sharp)

Comment: try `1U << i` ...

Comment: 1U worked, thanks pm100

Comment: Did you try that link above?

Comment: For copying bytes between all kinds of types, there is `Marshal.Copy()`. There are a few steps overhead before you can use that, which I would need to look up (hence no example). Perhaps someone can write an answer with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copying a `BitArray` to an `UInt32` is not supported by the implementation, according to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.bitarray.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx) which is quite recent (10/2016):

> The specified array must be of a compatible type. Only bool, int, and byte types of arrays are supported.

2. The most significant bit in an `int` is [used to store the sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30497009/1132334). To tell the compiler that you intend a numeric literal to be unsigned, use the U suffix: `1U << 31`

Answer (score 0):

The problems have been explained, but it hasn't been made explicit what you do about so, for completeness:

You should use `CopyTo` into an `int[]`, then convert your int to an uint, like this (not tested)

```
int[] temp = new int[1];
bits.CopyTo(temp);
uint asUint = unchecked((uint)temp[0]);
```

The `unchecked` is kind of silly, but you seem to have switched on the "check arithmetic by default" checkbox (otherwise `(uint)(1 << i)` would have worked - there is no inherent problem with that, it's only dangerous in a `checked` context).

Or even better than the above, if you `BitArray` is short you can avoid using it altogether and just always work with the bits of the `uint`.